# FailedPreconditionError Tensorflow Train

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am testing a code that colors images in Google Colab.

```py
from keras.models import Model, Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.layers import Input, UpSampling2D, RepeatVector, Reshape
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2, preprocess_input
from keras import backend as K

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

Using TensorFlow backend.
1.14.0
```

I am using tensorflow 1.14.0 because the original code is from Kaggle, the original: https://www.kaggle.com/valkling/image-colorization-using-autoencoders-and-resnet/notebook

There are no problems in any cell, until training. When excute this code is run its fail.

```py
%%time
BATCH_SIZE = 20
model.fit_generator(
    image_a_b_gen(X_train, BATCH_SIZE),
    epochs=30,
    verbose=1,
    steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE,
    callbacks=model_callbacks)
```

The error is:

```py
Epoch 1/30

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-14-61e8a51cf536> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', 'BATCH_SIZE = 20\nmodel.fit_generator(\n    image_a_b_gen(X_train, BATCH_SIZE),\n    epochs=30,\n    verbose=1,\n    steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE,\n    callbacks=model_callbacks)')

<decorator-gen-60> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

<timed exec> in <module>()

<timed exec> in image_a_b_gen(dataset, batch_size)

<timed exec> in create_inception_embedding(grayscaled_rgb)

1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1458                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1459         if run_metadata:
   1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable conv2d_45/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/conv2d_45/kernel)
     [[{{node conv2d_45/convolution/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

I think it may be related to the version of tensorflow or sessions, but I can't find any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How I thought the solution was very simple and related to version problems.

The version of keras and tensorflow in kaggle is 2.2.4 and 1.14.0 respectively. The solution is simple to change the version of Google Colab with these instructions:

```py
!pip install tensorflow==1.14.0
!pip install keras==2.2.4
```

Then restart de Notebook and its done.